Issue with Sort-Object for PSObject
I have a PSObject that holds more than one copy of the same name, I have tried to sort and print unique data from this object.
This is how the object populated:
foreach ($all in $allFiles) {
            $Issql = 'false'

            if ($all.Extension -eq ".sql") {
                $Issql = 'true'  
            }
            $dllpath = Convert-Path $all.PSPath
            $ParentCount = ($dllpath.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)).count

            for ($i = -2; $i -gt - $ParentCount; $i--) {
                $parentname = $dllpath.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)[$i]
                foreach ($r in $resultarray) {
                    if ($parentname -match $r.PackageName) {
                        foreach ($fil in $r.files) {
                            $dll_name = ($fil.Split([System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)[-1])
                            if ($dll_name -like '${TargetRootFolder}*') {
                                $dll_name = $dll_name.Replace('${TargetRootFolder}', '')
                            }

                            if ($Issql -eq 'true') {
                                $nameTocompare = $all.name -replace ("%20", " ")
                            }
                            else {
                                $nameTocompare = $all.name
                            }

                            #if ($all.name -match $dll_name) {
                            if ($nameTocompare -match $dll_name) {
                                $ExistPreAnalysis += @{
                                    PackageName = $r.PackageName 
                                    #DllName     = $file.Replace('\', '/')
                                    DllName     = $dll_name
                                    Patch       = $r.PatchNumber #$patchNum
                                }       
                            }
                        }
                    }  
                }
            }
        }

My object $ExistPreAnalysis holds the following:
As you can see there are duplicate values (18 instead of 9)
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1448763                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1485533                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1515427                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1518481                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1559928                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1600016                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1600905                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1615961                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          2029274                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1448763                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1485533                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1515427                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1518481                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1559928                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1600016                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1600905                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1615961                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          2029274                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase

I have tried many things like:
$ExistPreAnalysis = $ExistPreAnalysis | sort-Object -Unique -Property DllName, Patch, PackageName | Group-Object DllName | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } |  ForEach-Object { $_.Group }

This will return only 1:
$ExistPreAnalysis | sort-Object -Unique

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
DllName                        Pulling AD_Domain_Stored Procedures_PullAD-sp.sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Patch                          1448763                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PackageName                    IDUDatabase


Can you show us how you constructed/populated $ExistPreAnalysis in the first place? It looks like an array of dictionaries/hashtables...

The code added.

Make sure you cast your property table to [pscustomobject] in order to create a custom object:
$ExistPreAnalysis += [pscustomobject]@{
    PackageName = $r.PackageName 
    #DllName     = $file.Replace('\', '/')
    DllName     = $dll_name
    Patch       = $r.PatchNumber #$patchNum
}

Now you can target individual properties with commands like Sort-Object:
$ExistPreAnalysis |Sort-Object -Unique Patch


If for some reason you need to retain an array of hashtables and not custom objects, use a calculated property when invoking Sort-Object, then resolve the appropriate entry by name:
$ExistPreAnalysis |Sort-Object -Property {$_['Patch']} -Unique 


If you NEED $ExistPreAnalysis being a hashtable array, see This Answer
Otherwise, make it a PSCustomObject array as suggested by @Mathias R. Jessen instead:
[pscustomobject]@{
    PackageName = $r.PackageName 
    DllName     = $dll_name
    Patch       = $r.PatchNumber #$patchNum
}

Also, you should create the array by $ExistPreAnalysis = foreach #etc instead of adding each new element with +=: it's very inefficient
